# Sporadic high traffic

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, traffic, queue

Is there any software to handle sporadic high traffic web sites? My situation is the following: only two times a year my traffic spikes several orders of magnitude, i was wondering if some software existed (something like a queue) that can help me cope with this sporadic traffic.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well not really...

Queues are only good for async information.. ( this depends on what your application is doing) You could just scale up or out.. ( but this also might be a little expensive as an all round year solution :/ )

If you know when these time periods are, then you consider using the amazon cloud to deliver static images, or even using ec2 for cluster-cloud delivery...

Perhaps this could be an option for you ???
Depending on how much traffic we are talking about though..

Comment: The amazon cloud is a good option for this problem, but sadly the system needs live data and the owners of the data are very reticent to put it in other servers... I guess i'll develop my solution :)

Comment: The live data can be served and "cached" on the cloud..

There are ways to to maintain data integrity/security in the cloud..

Consider caching, where nothing actually "lives" on the cloud..